# Why does android click detection not work? (java)

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, interactive

So I am making a scrolling platformer game, and I want the player to jump when the screen is tapped. However, I have tried many many answers on Stack overflow such as `android:onClick`,

```
ImageButton imgButton;
imgButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Gameview", "clicked");
    }
});
```

and I suspect it does not work due to some sort of interaction between the gameView hiding the base screen and being displayed over it. How can I detect taps in my gameView or in general for game purposes?
Any help is much appreciated :D pulling my hair out over this

Comment: What type is `gameView`? Does it have a `setOnClickListener` or something similar?

Comment: It is a content view, `setContentView(new gameView(this));`
also no, i didnt know you could do that
could you please provide some example code for adding the onclicklistener to gameview

Comment: Can you please add full code of class and layout?

Comment: could you give more detail about your layout? I guess you have some layout that overlay imageButton and consume touch event

Comment: I cannot view your layout, thus I cannot be sure: you could have a widget above that consumes the touch event and doesn't propagate the event to the elements below. In this case you can choose the behaviour of that widget in `setOnTouchListener`, by returning `true` or `false`.